# How to creat Adobe Flash cs6 Actionscript 3 rtmp video player driven by an xml file?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, rtmp

Like the title says I would like to know how I can create a video player inside adobe flash cs6 driven by an xml file using actionscript 3.0.

I have read a lot about how to import data from an xml with actionscript 3.0 but never managed to get a rtmp video to work.

My project is to create an xml driven rtmp player inside adobe flash that has 5 different rtmp videos and will automatically switch videos per 5 seconds.

If someone could help me out with any of this I would be very thankful.

Comment: Hi, what is the backend for your project , are you using RED5 Live Streaming Server to feed your players?

Comment: Just random it does not matter what video.

Comment: Not Sure, this may help you [Displaying a video in Flex using the NetConnection](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/03/01/displaying-a-video-in-flex-using-the-netconnection-netstream-and-video-classes/)

Comment: thank you for trying to help me but this was not what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are novice in programming particularly with As3, I would recommend to go with ready to use solution. For example you could use [Strobe Media Playback](http://www.osmf.org/strobe_mediaplayback.html). It's powerful, easy to use, free, [easy to customise](http://www.osmf.org/downloads/pdf/using_fmp_smp_1.5.pdf), It works with RTMP connections, and you will be able create play list.

> Strobe Media Playback is an Open Source Media Framework (OSMF) based media player that you can quickly and easily integrate into your website. The compiled SWF and its source code are available for free download from this site.

Comment: I am not a novice programmer and also new to flash and actionscript. I just need a simple video player created in adobe flash that gets the data from a xml file to play rtmp videos